# verify input calculator application

Tags: asp.net, regex

Hello I need to test if the input is valid for calculator application:

```
 3 * 9
 100 + 20
 200 - 99
```

Here's my regex:

```
 (d).(*|+|-).(d)
```

but it doesn't seem to work. how can I verify and scrape the decimal values? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming ASP uses the standard notation, this should be

```
\d+\s[*+-]\s\d+
```